# Un-splitting data that crosses antimeridian in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, antimeridian

I'm working with a set of points in ArcMap that crosses the antimeridian (180°). I need to convert the points to a line but doing so creates a line that doubles back and forth across the globe to connect the data, instead of closing the line in closest distance terms.

How can I get arc to unspilt my data around the antimeridian for the both the map view and geoprocessing?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured this out. Changing the data frame projection to PCD Mercator (http://epsg.io/3832) centers view on pacific, running Point to Line on data with PCD Mercator produced un split pacific line.

[image]

Comment: You should tick your answer as solved so people know this was a solution.

Comment: I tried to but get a message that says I can "Accept my own answer tomorrow"?